# PHP MySQL Paypal

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I am creating a membership system and I need help with my paypal intergration. I need it to update my users table to change their membership status to active. Here is the code from success.php file:

```
include 'resource/dbConfig.php';

//Get payment information from PayPal
$item_number = $_GET['item_number']; 
$txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
$payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
$currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
$payment_status = $_GET['st'];

//Get product price from database
$productResult = $db->query("SELECT price FROM products WHERE id = ".$item_number);
$productRow = $productResult->fetch_assoc();
$productPrice = $productRow['price'];

if(!empty($txn_id) && $payment_gross == $productPrice){
//Check if payment data exists with the same TXN ID.
$prevPaymentResult = $db->query("SELECT payment_id FROM payments WHERE txn_id = '".$txn_id."'");

if($prevPaymentResult->num_rows > 0){
    $paymentRow = $prevPaymentResult->fetch_assoc();
    $last_insert_id = $paymentRow['payment_id'];
}else{
    //Insert tansaction data into the database
    $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO payments(item_number,txn_id,payment_gross,currency_code,payment_status) VALUES('".$item_number."','".$txn_id."','".$payment_gross."','".$currency_code."','".$payment_status."')");
    $last_insert_id = $db->insert_id;
}
```

?>

all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: *"I need it to update my users table"* - Start with the manual on UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html